# SetWindowsHookEx from static library

Tags: c++, windows, setwindowshookex

I'm trying to install a hook to intercept mouse and keyboard from a library to an executable. If I build the library as a Dynamically Loaded Library everything works fine, but when the I build the library as a static library it doesn't work.

To install the hook I do like this:

Get the library module handle with this function

```
HMODULE GetCurrentModule()
{
    return reinterpret_cast<HMODULE>(&__ImageBase);
}
```

Install the hook

```
HMODULE module = GetCurrentModule();
_windowsProcHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, WindowsProcCallback, module, NULL);
```

I've debugged the code and I've seen that when a build as a DLL, the module I get from `GetCurrentModule` is the correct one (from the DLL) but when I build as a static library `GetCurrentModule` returns the module of my executable.

Comment: A Windows module is an executable or dll. A static library provides some code and/or data for a module.

Comment: OK, but is there a way to install a hook from a static library?

Comment: This is entirely normal.  You **must** build it as a DLL if you want to set that hook, required so the DLL can be injected into the target process(es).  You cannot inject an EXE.

Comment: Well, you pass `NULL` as thread id, which means you want a global hook. That requires a DLL.

Comment: All right, so I could install the hook from the static library if I have the thread id right?

Comment: Can `GetCurrentThreadId` do the work? (only if building static library)